# ffmpeg overlay size

Tags: linux, filter, ffmpeg

I have the following ffmpeg command which puts an overlay image over the video. After ffmpeg encoding is done the overlay image appears too big, bigger then it's actual size. How do i control width and height dimensions for the overlay image.

```
ffmpeg -i 1.wmv -s 640x360 -f mp4 -b 800k -acodec libfaac -ab 64k -vf "movie=0:png:dollar.png [wm];[in][wm] overlay=0:0:1 [out]" out.mp4
```

Answer (score 6):

Try appending [filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#scale) settings with `scale=width:height` clause like this:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.wmv -s 640x360 -f mp4 -b 800k -acodec libfaac -ab 64k -vf "movie=0:png:dollar.png, scale=120:120 [wm];[in][wm] overlay=0:0:1 [out]" out.mp4
```

Comment: scale=120:120 doesn't resize the watermark. It does nothing. Did you try this out.

Comment: I've just used the scale syntax and it works in combination with movie, for an overlay, for example. Like: -vf 'movie=dollar.png, scale=120:120 [logo]; [in] ...'

Answer (score 3):

Try this worked for me : 
ffmpeg -i basevideo.xxx -vf "movie=overlayvid.xxx [in]; [in] scale=width:height [scale]; [in][scale] overlay=x:y [out]" output.xxx

Comment: It won't work as expected. You're defining `movie` stream as `[in]` and then scale it. And then overlay scaled `overlayvid` on `overlayvid`. And if scaled video is bigger than original ffmpeg won't even do anything and exit with error