# FFmpeg messes up image overlay's width after adding it to a video

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using the following command to overlay a given image onto a video:

```
ffmpeg -y \
-i "Input.mp4" \
-loop 1 -t 17 -i "overlay.png" \
-filter_complex \
"[1:v]fade=in:st=3:d=1:alpha=1, \
fade=out:st=10:d=1:alpha=1 \
[ovr1]; \
[0][ovr1] overlay=(W-w)/2:H-h-10" \
-codec:a copy \
"Output.mp4"
```

The command works but it results in an overlay with a width different than the input `overlay.png`, it has the same height, though.

Here's `overlay.png`:

[image: overlay.png preview]

And here's how it appears in the video after FFmpeg overlaying:

[image: video screenshot]

`overlay.png` size is `274x79`, but in the video it becomes about `324x79`.

I've checked this question ([ffmpeg overlay size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040458/ffmpeg-overlay-size)) which suggest the use of `scale`, I changed the command to the following:

```
ffmpeg -y \
-i "Input.mp4" \
-loop 1 -t 17 -i "overlay.png" \
-filter_complex \
"[1:v]scale=274:79 \
fade=in:st=3:d=1:alpha=1, \
fade=out:st=10:d=1:alpha=1 \
[ovr1]; \
[0][ovr1] overlay=(W-w)/2:H-h-10" \
-codec:a copy \
"Output.mp4"
```

But the results are still the same (bigger width), and I was able to confirm that `scale` does indeed work by editing it to `scale=400:400` to check its effect.

What caused this and how can I keep the original size of `overlay.png` after overlaying it onto the video?

---

**Edit:**

`ffmpeg -i Input.mp4` shows the following:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2018-12-30T12:38:54.000000Z
    encoder         : HandBrake 1.1.0 2018040700
  Duration: 00:00:17.45, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1179 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], 1174 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-12-30T12:38:54.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

Comment: Your video appears to be anamorphic  What does `ffmpeg -i input.mp4` say?

Comment: @Gyan I've edited my question to add `ffmpeg -i Input.mp4` output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your video is 720x480 but with a 16:9 display ratio, basically a widescreen SD NTSC video.

You'll need to make it a square pixel video before overlaying the image, using the scale and setsar filter.

So,

```
ffmpeg -y \
-i "Input.mp4" \
-loop 1 -t 17 -i "overlay.png" \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=2*trunc(iw*sar/2):ih,setsar=1[0v]; \
[1:v]fade=in:st=3:d=1:alpha=1, \
fade=out:st=10:d=1:alpha=1[ovr1]; \
[0v][ovr1] overlay=(W-w)/2:H-h-10" \
-codec:a copy \
"Output.mp4"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm getting the following error: `[libx264 @ 0000000002fd0500] width not divisible by 2 (853x480)`.

Comment: Corrected expr.

Comment: Needed to shift bracket

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked wonderfully! I've accepted the answer as well.